# Getting exception with msbuild while trying to build a project

Tags: .net, msbuild

While trying to build the project through ant.I am getting exception after the following statement :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```

Exception :

```
error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Version" task could not be loaded from the assembly \MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll)). Could not load file or assembly file:///C:\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll))' or one of its dependencies.
```

My project requires version 3.5.
My Msbuild.Community.Tasks.dll is of version 4.

I am not able to figure out why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its there a problems with the Path. 
try to change like this.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>.</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="packages\MSBuildTasks.yourversion\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the library and install from Nuget

PM> Install-Package MSBuildTasks

you can find all' informations about this Library https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

Comment: I have the MSbuild tasks installed on my system.but still I am getting this error.